# Changing the image in UIimageView

Tags: ios7

Hi I am new to ios programming,
I am trying to change the image of UIImageView outletImage

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    dragView *dragViewCopy=[[dragView alloc]init];
    newPic=[dragViewCopy imageChanger];

    outletImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)newPic];
    NSLog(@"vc %@",newPic);   
}
```

but it is not changing,inspite that the correct name of the image appears when i test it with NSLog
when i try this

```
outletImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)@"bird.png];
```

it works

Can anybody help me about this
thanks

Comment: What does the `[dragViewCopy imageChanger]` method return? An NSString or a UIImage?

Comment: Try to redraw view after image change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you're trying to load an image from disk (or whatever the iOS device's hard drive equivalent is) and the actual image you have (which comes from the "`imageChanger`") method is entirely within memory.

So instead of doing "`[UIImage imageNamed:]`", you may want to create your image using "`[UIImage alloc] initWithData:`" or use whatever actual object type "`imageChanger`" returns.